# How to extract html through Javascript executor?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;       

public class oo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Java\\Lib\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();         
      driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");

      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
      Object s = js.executeScript("return document.body.innerHTML;",null).toString();

      System.out.println(s);
      driver.close();
   }
}
```

Above code returns nullPointerException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Arrays.stream(Unknown Source) at java.util.stream.Stream.of(Unknown Source) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:484) at oo.main(oo.java:25)
```

When I remove optional object parameter, it goes compilation error.

Code:

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
  Object s = js.executeScript("return document.body.innerHTML;").toString();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:     The method executeScript(String, Object[]) in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Using Selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Comment: When I remove optional object parameter, it goes compilation error. -> if it stops compiling, the parameter is not optional

Comment: What's the meaning of s Object? It will be propably always null.

Comment: do you really need to use an external API? I mean, with Java 8, there is Nashorn

Comment: did you try `new Object[]{}` as second param? The docs say "may be empty" which doesn't mean "may be null"

Comment: It doesnt allow to remove second optional 'arguments' parameter. Goes for compilation error.

Comment: Did you try something like `driver.findElementByTagName("body").getAttribute("innerHTML").toString()`?

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is because you are sending `null` as args. Did you try without it?

Comment: Without null as second argument, it goes compilation error. But as per syntax, arguments list is optional. It's confusing.

Comment: Object executeScript(String script, Object... args); It can be called with a single param of a String type. Just checked it. Are you sure you got a compilation error?

Comment: Yes I am sure I am getting compilation error. 
The method executeScript(String, Object[]) in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 1):

To *extract* and *print* the *Page Source* through *JavascriptExecutor* you can use the following (**Java** based) solution:

- Syntax:

  ```
  String page_source = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;").toString();
  System.out.println(page_source);
  ```

**Note**: You need to induce a waiter for the page to load completely before extracting the *Page Source*.