# Selenium WebDriverWait keeps throwing a TimeoutException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait, timeoutexception

I am using Selenium to login to as follows:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,'email'))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have also tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='email']"))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
```

Here is the source HTML code I am accessing:

```
<div id="signup-form">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h1 data-i18n="signin">Sign in</h1>
    <div class="panels-wrapper">
        <div class="panels">
            <div class="panel step-1">
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" required="" maxlength="100">
                <label for="email" data-i18n="email">Email</label>
```

Appreciate any guidance to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to take care.

In case the element is within a [frame](/questions/tagged/frame) / [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe), without the relevant [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428409/get-fully-rendered-html-using-selenium-webdriver-and-python/52428875#52428875) it would be tough to construct a canonical answer. However, as per the [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411703/how-to-extract-html-through-javascript-executor/53414048#53414048) you have shared, I don't see the presence of any `<frame>` / `<iframe>`.

---

Generally, to send a *character sequence* within the element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email[name='email']"))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email' and @name='email']"))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to click on a element through Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511)

---

In case the element is within a you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('site_url')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe_cssSelector")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email[name='email']"))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('site_url')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe_xpath")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email' and @name='email']"))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

    > You can find a relevant discussion in [Unable to type within username field within ProtonMail signup page using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365613/unable-to-type-within-username-field-within-protonmail-signup-page-using-seleniu/62366143#62366143)

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Thanks! The CSS_SELECTOR worked. The login was in a pop-up so I had to add this too:

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

Answer (score 1):

Email is not a frame. The condition you are using is used for frame( iframe tag ) but here you are dealing with input tag. So I suggest you to check either the visibility of that element or presence of that element based on your requirement.

Comment: thanks. I tried the following and i still get a "timeout exception message" error:

      WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='email']"))).send_keys("mymail@gmail.com")